# sql - how to cycle a foreign key to obtain a cycled list of elements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cycle

I've those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Keeping in mind I've more than 5 users with more than 100 posts each one, I want to obtain a cycle response to don't repeat the same user twice:

```
+---------+---------+
| id      | user_id |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       |
| 23      | 2       |
| 12      | 3       |
| 50      | 4       |
| 25      | 5       |
| 23      | 1       |
| 22      | 2       |
| 77      | 3       |
...
```

The idea is the user_id column cycle to don't repeat twice the same value, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not clear what you want here. Are you looking for a way to create some dummy data, or a way to take a sample of existing data? Do you need to be able to page through it? Should the order of id values be random, or is there some other logic? Or am I completely misunderstanding?

Comment: @IMSoP no, the mission is cycle the user_id to don't repeat the same user_id twice. Check the answer by klin is just what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` for each `user_id` separately and use it to determine the order of results:

```
select id, user_id
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id) rn
    from posts
    ) s
order by rn, user_id;
```